# Different values for mass by conservation of energy and Newton's Laws of motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, mass, spring

A vertical ideal spring with spring constant of 92 N/m is placed on top of a lab bench. A block of unknown mass, m, is dropped onto the spring from a height of 1.1 meters above the lab bench. Before the block hits the spring, the spring is 0.4 meters long. Once the block comes to rest after hitting the spring, the spring is now 0.07 meters long. What is the mass of the block?

I am using conservation of energy and Newton's laws of motion to calculate the mass.
By conservation of energy, i  am getting m $\approx$ 0.46 kg but with Newton's laws, i am getting 3.1 kg( The mass comes to rest so i am assuming it is equilibrium position).

But the two methods should give me the same value regardless, please help!

**Edit 1 : The equations:**

**From conservation of energy:** $mgh = \frac{1}{2} k x^2$
So, mass is simply $m= \frac{1}{2} k x^2/gh$
here $h = 1.1 m$ ; x = compression of spring= $0.4-0.07$ $=0.33$
This gives me m $\approx$ 0.46 kg.

**From Newton's law:** $mg = kx$
SO, $m=kx/g$
This gives me $m = 3.1 kg$

**Edit:2** I should specify that I am not simply looking for people to solve this for me and give me an answer so that I can copy-paste. No, what is bothering me is that "***why the two methods are not giving the same answer***" when the system is supposedly at rest, which would mean  equilibrium.

Comment: You should show your calculation! Your results  seem strange

Comment: Added the equations!

Comment: Imagine laying your block very gently on top of the spring vs. throwing it onto the spring. Clearly, even if the mass is the same, the spring will be deformed more in the latter case. Energy conservation is the only reliable way here since force is the change in momentum.

Comment: Voting to reopen. Clearly a conceptual question and not a "do my homework for me" question.

Comment: @gandalf61 No. It's a "find my mistake for me" question, which is again off-topic. There is nothing conceptual about this.

Comment: @JustaPhysicist The coming to rest part is unclear. If you mean the moment when it is instantaneously at rest immediately after hitting the spring for the first time, then conservation of energy is the right approach. If you mean after a long time (many bounces), when it finally settles into its final state of rest atop the spring, then force balance is the right approach.

Comment: Hello, yes that's what is confusing me, i do no simply need an answer to this, the calculations by each method are quite simple enough. What is bothering  me is 'the coming to rest part' as well but that is how the question is worded.

Comment: @JustaPhysicist "coming to rest" implies that energy is dissipated to the environment so you cannot use conservation of energy here as you do not know how much energy has been dissipated. Your second method is correct.

Comment: @JustaPhysicist Then the question is unclear and you should ask your teacher. This site is for asking conceptual physics questions rather than clarifying the semantics of specific homework/exercise questions.

Comment: "why the two methods are not giving the same answer" Why do you expect them to give the same answer? I have already explained in my previous comment. Both methods are conceptually correct and valid, but they are answering **different** questions.

Comment: @VincentThacker, I do understand that the site is not about asking homework problems. The main motivation behind posting the question here was to get a second or perhaps more experienced opinion from other physicists that whether both the methods are applicable in this case or not, as the question doesn't make it clear.  I have stated in my edits or in previous comments that the equations themselves are quite easy, it is the concept/idea of their applicability. I did have a feeling that two cases are different but then question was which one you would consider as the correct method?

Comment: Anyway, thank you for the clarification that it is unclear from the question itself and that I am not doing anything wrong conceptually.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the wording of the question is correct, specificially the "Once the block comes to rest after hitting the spring, the spring is now 0.07 meters long." part, my answer would be 3.098 kg. I got this by calculating the force needed to compress the spring to a length of the 0.07 meters, 30.36 N, with Hooke's Law. Then equating that to the weight of the block under earths gravity. Below is the afforementioned calculation:

At rest, $W_{block} = F_{spring}$

$W_{block} = m_bg$

$F_{spring} = k\Delta x$

$m_bg = k\Delta x$

$m_b * 9.8 = 92 * 0.33$

$m_b = \frac{92 * 0.33}{9.8} \approx 3.098$ kg

I believe your solution with conservation of energy would not work since, in this scenario, energy is not conserved. After the spring is hit by  the block it will oscillate, losing energy to air resistance and other nonconservative forces.

Comment: This answer and the calculation  of the Just a Physicist with allegedly Newtons law are wrong, both do not take in account the speed the mass has hitting the spring. Only the energy helps but with h=1,43m

Comment: No, while the question was written in an odd manor, it deals with the spring and mass when they come to rest, so it can be simplified into "A block resting on a spring, with spring constant 92 N/m, compresses said spring 0.33 meters from its equilibrium position, what is the mass of the block?"

Comment: True, this exercise was more of a reading comprehension than a physics question.